# Centre of mass of a random 3D polygon (obj file or stl file)

Tags: java, 3d, java-3d, wavefront, stl-format

Currently I have an ArrayList of vertices in a 3-dimensional cartesian coordinates system. The polygon is random. It can be a car, a cup or even a dragon.

Assuming the density does not change, how to calculate the centre of mass (x,y,z) of this 3D object?

I am storing the faces and vertices in ArrayList.

```
public ArrayList<stlFace> StlFaces = new ArrayList<stlFace>();
public ArrayList<VertexGeometric> VertexList = new ArrayList<VertexGeometric>();
```

Comment: You need to compute the integral of the moments of the mass and divide that by the total mass. This is well-documented on the internet. Time for a Google ;-) And before you delve too deeply, you may well find a library function to do it for you.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thank you! Do you have any good link? I think integral should be the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I was using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128991/how-to-calculate-area-of-3d-triangle) for calculating surface which is proportional to mass of each face or triangle. And to calculate center off mass of each triangle and center of mass of whole object I was using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass). I added helper methods getCenter() and getSurface() to Face class to encapsulate calculations specific to just one face/triangle.

```
public static class Vertex {

    public float x = 0;
    public float y = 0;
    public float z = 0;

    public Vertex(float x, float y, float z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}

public static class Face {

    public Vertex v1;
    public Vertex v2;
    public Vertex v3;

    public Face(Vertex v1, Vertex v2, Vertex v3) {
        this.v1 = v1;
        this.v2 = v2;
        this.v3 = v3;
    }

    public Vertex getCenter() {
        Vertex triangleCenter = new Vertex(0, 0, 0);
        triangleCenter.x += v1.x;
        triangleCenter.x += v2.x;
        triangleCenter.x += v3.x;
        triangleCenter.y += v1.y;
        triangleCenter.y += v2.y;
        triangleCenter.y += v3.y;
        triangleCenter.z += v1.z;
        triangleCenter.z += v2.z;
        triangleCenter.z += v3.z;
        triangleCenter.x /= 3;
        triangleCenter.y /= 3;
        triangleCenter.z /= 3;
        return triangleCenter;
    }

    public float getSurface() {
        float x1 = v1.x - v2.x;
        float x2 = v1.y - v2.y;
        float x3 = v1.z - v2.z;
        float y1 = v1.x - v3.x;
        float y2 = v1.y - v3.y;
        float y3 = v1.z - v3.z;
        return (float) Math.sqrt(
                Math.pow(x2 * y3 - x3 * y2, 2) + 
                Math.pow(x3 * y1 - x1 * y3, 2) + 
                Math.pow(x1 * y2 - x2 * y1, 2)
            ) / 2f;
    }
}

public static Vertex calculateMassCenter(List<Face> faces) {
    Vertex massCenter = new Vertex(0, 0, 0);
    float mass = 0;
    for (Face face : faces) {
        Vertex triangleCenter = face.getCenter();
        float faceMass = face.getSurface();
        mass += faceMass;
        massCenter.x += faceMass * triangleCenter.x;
        massCenter.y += faceMass * triangleCenter.y;
        massCenter.z += faceMass * triangleCenter.z;
    }
    massCenter.x /= mass;
    massCenter.y /= mass;
    massCenter.z /= mass;
    return massCenter;
}
```